# How to rotate 2d vector?

Tags: c#, rotation, vector-graphics

I have this:

```
static double[] RotateVector2d(double x, double y, double degrees)
{
    double[] result = new double[2];
    result[0] = x * Math.Cos(degrees) - y * Math.Sin(degrees);
    result[1] = x * Math.Sin(degrees) + y * Math.Cos(degrees);
    return result;
}
```

When I call

```
RotateVector2d(1.0, 0, 180.0)
```

the result is: `[-0.59846006905785809, -0.80115263573383044]`

What to do so that the result is `[-1, 0]` ?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Documentation says that Math.Cos expects a double d as parameter - should be double r or double radians to clarify.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The angle is measured in radians, not degrees. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.cos(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you too (you have been 4 sec after J...)

Comment: @MartinMeeser by my clock, he beat me by 8 seconds.

Comment: First! Jk, I really don't care

Comment: @J... ok so i marked this as the answer and upvoted your answer you were just both right and at the same time.

Answer (score 25):

A couple of things:
Use `Vector` to represent vectors.

- v.X reads better than v[0]
- It is a struct so it will have nice performance.
- Be aware that `Vector` is a mutable struct.

For rotation perhaps an extension method makes sense:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

public static class VectorExt
{
    private const double DegToRad = Math.PI/180;

    public static Vector Rotate(this Vector v, double degrees)
    {
        return v.RotateRadians(degrees * DegToRad);
    }

    public static Vector RotateRadians(this Vector v, double radians)
    {
        var ca = Math.Cos(radians);
        var sa = Math.Sin(radians);
        return new Vector(ca*v.X - sa*v.Y, sa*v.X + ca*v.Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Include the whole System.Windows namespace just to get a vector struct? I do not consider this a good idea neither to have good performance. I think this namespace is WinForms specific?

Comment: I also disagree that v.X reads better then v[0], I think it is well agreed that v[x,y,z] can be used.

Comment: Valid point about bringing in `System.Windows` there are Vectors in other places in the framework though. Or roll your own.

About readability: using a `Vector` instead on `double[]` cannot be compared on the same day imo.

About perf: Without benchmarking I'd expect a struct to be ~1000x faster than using `double[]`

Comment: Can you please explain why a struct{double, double} should be faster then double[2]? Or provide a link? Looking at the raw bytes I would expect it to look the same. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I expected stack vs heap allocation to make a big difference but when I ran a benchmark the struct was only 25% faster. Must have a look at the IL, either there is some crazy optimization for arrays or I dumbed the [benchmark](https://github.com/JohanLarsson/BenchmarkBox/blob/master/BenchmarkBox/RotateVector.cs)

Comment: @MartinMeeser Arrays are slower both because they have to be bounds-checked, and because they are reference objects whereas structs are value objects. And structs are superior because they are type-safe (and are more readable). Also, System.Windows.Vector is WPF, not WinForms. And it's the assembly, not the namespace, that adds overhead, but nothing significant to performance. If you aren't using WPF and have sound, rational objections to including it, just define your own Vector struct.

Comment: Just note: these calculations are valid for both: right-hand coordinate system & left-hand.

Answer (score 5):

`Sin` and `Cos` take values in radians, not degrees.  180 degrees is `Math.PI` radians.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative if you want to use degrees without conversion using Matrix:

```
    System.Windows.Media.Matrix m = new System.Windows.Media.Matrix();
    m.Rotate((double)angle_degrees);
    System.Windows.Vector v = new System.Windows.Vector(x,y);
    v = System.Windows.Vector.Multiply(v, m);
```

Comment: Can you please add namespaces for matrix and vector?
In my case adding huge namespaces for just that issue was overhead.

Comment: Yes, that's something to take into account. In my case I already was using theses namespaces in my app and it seemed to me easier this solution than other answers.

Comment: As also noted at the other answer, System.Windows is - correct me if I am wrong - a WinForms specific namespace.

Comment: Seems related to wpf that I use for my UI. It is true that for a not wpf app, it is a bit too much to include it just for this.

Comment: @MartinMeeser You're wrong; it's WPF. System.Windows.Forms is WinForms.